# subscription filter for AWS CloudWatch logs to weed out Lambda Report messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm using a subscription filter to get logs from a specific log group to Firehose which will eventually put it into Elasticsearch. The logs in this log group are from a Java Lambda. All the `START RequestId ...`, `END RequestId ...` and `REPORT RequestId ...` messages also end up in Elasticsearch.

Is it possible to have a subscription filter so that these messages don't reach firehose and only the actual log messages from Lambda function reach the firehose. Or, is processing them with a "Transformation Lambda" the only way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible. It's a bit cryptic, but here's a filter pattern that will do the trick:

```
[a != "START" && a != "END" && a != "REPORT" && a != "RequestId:", ...]
```

When tested against:

```
START RequestId: 9538d388-c156-4680-b9d0-ba98c73742c7 Version: $LATEST
2019-02-06T20:30:49.096Z    9538d388-c156-4680-b9d0-ba98c73742c7    Hello World
END RequestId: 9538d388-c156-4680-b9d0-ba98c73742c7
REPORT RequestId: 9538d388-c156-4680-b9d0-ba98c73742c7  Duration: 24.45 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 47 MB  
RequestId: 9538d388-c156-4680-b9d0-ba98c73742c7 Process exited before completing request
```

Only this will match:

```
2019-02-06T20:30:49.096Z    9538d388-c156-4680-b9d0-ba98c73742c7    Hello World
```

Comment: that is awesome, thank you.  I cannot find much information at all about how to create these.  What is the `, ...` at the end?  Can we give names to the columns?  When I use this filter above in the CloudWatch test pattern screen, it does work, but my columns are $a, $2, $3, and $4.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: ok, I think I got it `[timestamp != "START" && timestamp != "END" &&timestamp != "REPORT" && timestamp != "RequestId:", aws_request_id, log]`